# Add video from youtube in post (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I need to add video from youtube in certain place on my page.
I added link in post like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXGR7puGRpg` (post contains only this link), and then I added code on my page

```
<?php
$post_id_63 = get_post( $post_id = 63 );
if($post_id_63) {
    $post_id_63_content = $post_id_63->post_content;
    echo $post_id_63_content;
}
?>
```

but I get just text link on my page, not video. What did I do wrong? How to fix it and make it work ?
Maybe I should use some good plugin?

Comment: Please check if this help you : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get

Comment: I tried to use `echo wp_oembed_get($post_id_63_content);` and it works, thank you, but is there any opportunity to make video adaptive and use container width to set its size?

Comment: you can provide specific width to video , that example is also there in my shared reference link.

Comment: I used this solution to make video responsive http://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

Comment: I see then everything is working now as per your need?

Comment: Yes, all works great!